# How to download multiple files in local system using POST API request in python rather than in ascii or binary form data?

Tags: python

I struck in one scenario in which i need to download multiple files in local repository using POST API request in python 3.9.12.

I tried below code but not able to resolve the issue.

```
def download(url: str, dest_folder: str):
    if not os.path.exists(dest_folder):
        os.makedirs(dest_folder)

    filename = url.split('/')[-1].replace(" ", "_")
    file_path = os.path.join(dest_folder, filename)

    payload = {'testcaseId': '305432601'}

    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), stream=False)
    if r.ok:
        print("saving to", os.path.abspath(file_path))
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 8):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
                    f.flush()
                    os.fsync(f.fileno())
    else:  # HTTP status code 4XX/5XX
        print("Download failed: status code {}\n{}".format(r.status_code, r.text))


download("https://api.demo.com/siteapi/resultfiles/", dest_folder="//PycharmProjects//Testing_Local//Logs")
```

When I used above code it gives me below error:

> Download failed: status code 500
> {"timestamp":"2024-03-14T11:45:42.109+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal
> Server Error","path":"/siteapi/resultfiles/"}

**In postman we have that option to SEND and DOWNLOAD files and through that i am able to download multiple files in zip folder in my local system.**

[image]

My questions are :

1. How to download multiple files in local system or directory using
   python through POST API request rather than binary stream ?
2. How to achieve task through python code which postman UI is providing
   through SEND and DOWNLOAD option ?

Below scenario is expected :

1. Fire POST API request
2. DOWNLOAD Files through response of POST API
3. STORE files in local directory.